# Nearly there, just need a little push in the right direction with this wage calculation?

Tags: java

Help needed to calculate wages for two different pay scales! The error was the net total was incorrect. Thank you to all the comments they were very helpful and now it works :) I hope this part of my code can help other beginners learning to use loops and if statements:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
    DecimalFormat Currency = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");

    double normHrs = 0, overHrs = 0, bonusHrs = 0, actualHrs = 0, normPay = 0, overPay =0, bonusPay = 0, grossWage = 0,vat23 = 0, netWage =0;
    String empName, nextEMP = "y";



    System.out.println ("************************"); 
    System.out.println ("HUMAN RESOURCES: PAYROLL"); // 
    System.out.println ("************************"); 


    while (nextEMP.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        System.out.print("Please enter an employee's first name: "); 
        empName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter their total hours worked: ");
        actualHrs = input.nextDouble();


        if (actualHrs <=36)
        {
            normHrs=actualHrs;

        }

        else
        {

            normHrs = 36;
            bonusHrs = actualHrs - 50;
            overHrs = actualHrs -36;  
        }

        if ("bob".equalsIgnoreCase(empName))
        {
            bonusPay = bonusHrs > 0 ? bonusHrs : 0;
            normPay = normHrs * 8; // £8 x 36 hours
            overPay = overHrs * 12;  // £12 x 36+ hours 

        } 

        else
        {
            bonusPay = bonusHrs >0 ? 20 : 0;
            normPay = normHrs * 5.75; 
            overPay = overHrs * 9.25; 

        }


        }
```

Comment: I would cross post this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some tips on laying this code out better and making it more readable too.

Comment: Looks like it's time to familiarize yourself with using your debugger.

Comment: I am just a beginner and have followed the instructions set by the tutor.  We have to keep to the basics before making code efficient but thank you for the tip :)

Comment: What do you mean by _it will not calculate hours_? Can you give us an example of input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: In every IDE I know, there's a debugger. Which one are you using? If you cannot use debugger, you will need some output from the execution(print all variables in different lines) to see what's wrong.

Comment: The `bonusPay` calculation for bob does not seem to be correct, is this really what you want?

Comment: @user3058983 Yeah, you do have a debugger. If you're not using an IDE, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html

Comment: sorry Keppil : Bob is team leader and gets £8 per hour @ 36hrs, if he works 36+ (but less than 50hrs) he gets £12 per hour. If he works over 50 hours he gets a £1 extra per hour.... hope this helps?

Comment: @user3058983: Give us a concrete example instead, with what you input, what result you expect to get, and what the program outputs.

Comment: Output:
Please enter an employee's first name:Bob
Please enter their total hours worked:36
GROSS: 288.0
VAT @ 23% : 66.24000000000001
Net Pay: 221.76
Would you like to log hours for another employee?
y
Please enter an employee's first name:Bob
Please enter their total hours worked:40                       GROSS: 368.0
VAT @ 23% : 84.64
Net Pay: 283.36
working 40 hours should display = gross @ £480 vat @ 110.40 net pay @ £369.60

Comment: it seems to be ignoring the code which allows hours above 36 to be calculated at £12 per hour.  The results at 40 hours is being calculated at £8 per hour (which is incorrect)

Comment: Put System.out.println("\t\\bonusPay: "+ bonusPay+"\n\t\normPay : "+normPay+"\n\t\toverPay: "+overPay); in if("bob". as last statment and see that it is doing right.

Comment: in your code, if 40 hours entered, 36 hours is calculated at £8 per hour and the rest of 4 hours is calculated at £12 per hour. Is that not you are trying. Or do you want the whole 40 hours to be calculated at £12 per hour?

Comment: @ray yes that's what I am trying to achieve. Unfortunately the program calculates 40hrs at £8 - but the overpay is working :)

Comment: To get the desired results you can change " normPay = (actualHrs <=36)?actualHrs * 8:actualHrs * 12; overPay = 0;  " inside  if("bob".

Comment: There seems to be a lot of extra information needed to get this question some form of clarity: try not to put it all in comments, but update the question! The goal is not to make a big forum topic-like mess in the comments, but have a clear, usefull question that can get an answer: so I 'd suggest you add some of the information (what you want, what you get, etc) to the question so one can read all important infomation at once instead of in the comments. Good luck!

Comment: thank you @Nanne I will do in future :)

Comment: I cant count - its woooorks haha!! duh!

Answer (score 2):

In the if block you have a mistake when assigning *normPay*:

```
if ("bob".equalsIgnoreCase(empName)) {
            bonusPay = bonusHrs > 50 ? bonusHrs : 0; 
            normPay = actualHrs * 8; // £8 x 36 hours
            overPay = overHrs * 12;  // £12 x 36+ hours  
}
```

It must be

```
normPay = normHrs * 8;
```

Comment: The current GROSS result for bob with 37hr is £308. This is wrong, it should be 36x8 + 1x12 = £300. After the bug fix above, the result is £300.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the part that evaluates if Bob should get bonus.

Since you've already calculated `bonusHrs` as `actualHrs - 50`, this:

```
bonusPay = bonusHrs > 50 ? bonusHrs : 0;
```

will only give Bob bonus pay only when `actualHrs` is 100+ . It should probably be:

```
bonusPay = bonusHrs > 0 ? bonusHrs : 0;
```

Also, this:

```
normPay = actualHrs * 8; // £8 x 36 hours
```

Might be wrong and should maybe be:

```
normPay = normHrs * 8; // £8 x 36 hours
```